# Computing integrals of differential forms

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

How do I compute the integral of the differntial form $\omega =  xdy - y dx$ on $\mathbb R^2\backslash \{0\}$ along the path $\gamma(t) = (\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$?

That is, what is $\int_{\gamma} \omega$?

I think it is $2 \pi$. I simply substitute $x = \cos(2\pi t)$ and $y = \sin(2\pi t)$ and integrate from $t = 0$ to $t=1$. Is that correct?

What about the integral $\int_{\gamma} \omega_2$, where $\omega_2 = x^2 dy - y^2 dx$? Is this more difficult?

Answer (score 1):

Given the differential form
$$
\omega(x,y)=a(x,y)dx+b(x,y)dy
$$
its integral along the curve
$$
x=x(t)\\
y=y(t)\\
a\leq t\leq b
$$
is given by
$$
\int_a^b [a(x(t),y(t))x'(t)+b(x(t),y(t))y'(t)]dt
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you should take a look at Green's Theorem. Be sure to verify the conditions for Green's Theorem.